# Client - Server model using Dart as Client and Go language as Server

Tags: javascript, web, go, dart, angular-dart

I am trying to understand google two programing language.

Dart --> Produce Javascript

Go   --> Produce machine code

If I need to combine Client - Server model. I am wondering how the architecture works.

How does it work. Is there any example/sample.

Example : Please explain this.....

I type www.learnlang.com. I expect WEB UI is served using Dart and It is calling REST API developed in GO language.

Note : Please don't relate google app engine. I am trying to understand the model in individual servers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you got it right! So for example you compile your dart app using `dart2js` to produce javascript code. Then you can serve this code through a web server (like Apache or Nginx).

This code gets downloaded by clients as Javascript. Your Javascript code may connect to a backend written in Go through HttpRequests or WebSockets.

You can exchange data through both layers with JSON, XML, whatever you want.

Go will most likely run as a process, and embed its own "listening to HttpRequests" mechanism for the API.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is the expected answer.